# find a records which exists for 2 values only

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-division

I have Table structure/Data set is like this.

```
Emp_id  Expense_amt_dollar  Dept
1111    100                 Marketing    
1111    75                  Finance
1111    25                  IT
2222    100                 Marketing
3333    50                  Finance
4444    30                  Marketing
4444    70                  Finance
5555    200                 IT
```

O/P 
I am looking for Emp  expense in 2 dept only

```
Emp_id  Expense_amt_dollar  Dept
1111    100                 Marketing
1111    75                  Finance
4444    30                  Marketing
4444    70                  Finance
```

Emp  which having  records  for  these 2  dept only.
Records  should have for both dept.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where t.dept in ('Finance', 'Marketing')
and exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where emp_id = t.emp_id and dept in ('Finance', 'Marketing') and dept <> t.dept
)
```

or with a CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select t.* from tablename t
  where t.dept in ('Finance', 'Marketing')
)
select c.* from cte c
where exists (
  select 1 from cte 
  where emp_id = c.emp_id and dept <> c.dept
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82f33cbb611631356eae4169850205eb).
Results:

```
> EMP_ID | EXPENSE_AMT_DOLLAR | DEPT     
> -----: | -----------------: | :--------
>   1111 |                 75 | Finance  
>   1111 |                100 | Marketing
>   4444 |                 70 | Finance  
>   4444 |                 30 | Marketing
```

Answer (score 1):

> Emp which having records for these 2 dept only. Records should have for both dept.

I would use window functions:

```
select emp_id, expense_amt_dollar, dept
from (
    select 
        e.*, 
        sum(case when dept in ('Marketing', 'Finance') then 1 end) over(partition by emp_id) cnt_deps
        sum(case when dept not in ('Marketing', 'Finance') then 1 end) over(partition by emp_id) cnt_other_deps
    from emp e
) e
where cnt_deps = 2 an cnt_other_deps is null
```

This gives you records for employees that belong to both departments *and* to no other department - which is how I understand your question. For this, you need to look over the whole table: filtering with a `where` clause would prevent you from checking that the employee does not belong to any other department.

Comment: I assume Shyam means only employees with both departments, not with the two departments only. Hence employee 1111 in the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be producing a subquery with `having count(distinct dept) = 2` clause and then joining with the same table.

```
select t1.*
  from tab t1
  join (select emp_id, max(dept) dept1, min(dept) dept2
          from tab
         where dept in ('Finance', 'Marketing')
         group by emp_id
        having count(distinct dept) = 2) t2
    on t1.emp_id = t2.emp_id
   and t1.dept in (t2.dept1, t2.dept2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select the marketing and finance rows and then check whether you get both for an employee:

```
select *
from
(
  select emp_id, dept, count(*) over (partition by emp_id) as cnt
  from mytable t
  where dept in ('Marketing', 'Finance')
)
where cnt = 2
order by emp_id, dept;
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked in Postgresql:

```
select * 
from employee_expenses
where emp_id in 
(
select emp_id from employee_expenses 
where dept = 'Finance'
intersect
select emp_id from employee_expenses
where dept ='Marketing'
)
and dept in ('Finance', 'Marketing');
```